# Animate opacity of an element

Tags: jquery, css

How would one go about animating the "opacity" of an element using CSS or jQuery?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. Are you talking about jQuery `.fadeOut()` / `.fadeIn()`?

Comment: Awesome downvote, well done! If the OP doesn't even have sense enough to be a native English speaker, well, he *deserves* to be downvoted, by Jingo! I ***particularly*** like that you downvoted with no commentary; that's the spirit!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, using CSS transitions:

```css
div {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;    /* FF4+ */
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;      /* Opera 10.5+ */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; /* Safari 3.2+, Chrome */
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;     /* IE10+ */
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;         /* standard format */
}

div:hover {
    opacity: 0.3;    
}
```

```html
<div>Hover over me with your mouse!</div>
<div>Hover over me with your mouse!</div>
<div>Hover over me with your mouse!</div>
<div>Hover over me with your mouse!</div>
<div>Hover over me with your mouse!</div>
<div>Hover over me with your mouse!</div>
```

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer? Thanks for sharing exactly what I needed

Comment: @Awena Thanks for alerting me to this post. I've also included the example into a snippet instead of relying on a 3rd party.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 transitions can do it.  I'm doing the following for a mouse-activated toolbar:

css

```
<style type="text/css">
#cmsToolBar {
    font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: black;
    background-color: #DDDDBB;
    opacity: 0.15;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px black;
    transition-duration: .2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .2s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
    -o-transition-duration: .2s;
}
#cmsToolBar:hover {
    min-height: 5em;
    opacity: .98;
}
</style>
```

html

```
<div id="cmsToolBar">
  <p>This is where the CMS tool bar will go</p>
</div>
```

Comment: remember -ms-transition for IE10pp2... Also I'd add transition without a vendor prefix for future compatibility.

Comment: Didn't know about the IE version.  But the example above already has a generic transition defined.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to use `.fadeIn('slow or fast')` or `.fadeOut('slow or fast')`

Comment: These are not the only two options for specifiying speed in a jQuery animation.