# Make .removeClass() and .addClass() transition smoothly on scoll up and down

Tags: javascript

I am trying to transfer between display:none, and display:block. The div with the id #octopus-head is supposed to fade out when scrolling down, and back in when scrolling up, but right now it just pops in or out instantly.

Here is the javascript I am working with:

```js
//sticky header scripts

// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = jQuery('.scroll-height-setter').innerHeight();

jQuery(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 100);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        jQuery('#octopus-head').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up').fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + jQuery(window).height() < jQuery(document).height()) {
            jQuery('#octopus-head').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down').fadeIn(1000);
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Comment: You can't animate `display:none`. You have to use `opacity`.

Comment: Can you include any relevant HTML?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708874/animate-opacity-of-an-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display none cannot use transitions as there is nothing to transition from.

You could use setTimeout() to add a transition class that renders the div with opacity of zero and then switch classes to your final opacity 100%.

Or you could just always use opacity and never display none the div. It depends on what you actually need.